# Get pageLocation in realtime GA4 report

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am trying to get the pageLocation (URL) of the visited pages on my website in Google Analytics 4 via API (I find it messy and difficult).

Anyway, I eventually wrote a code that succesfully connects to the API, but I can't use the pageLocation dimension to get the URLs. Are really [only these dimensions allowed](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema)?

We have a big issue beacuse we can't track the AMP pages in real time in GA4: now everything is joined in the title. I can access the pageLocation only in reports, which are not updated in realtime.